# Convert Dictionary to String and back in python

Tags: string, python-3.x, dictionary, abstract-syntax-tree

I am writing to a dictionary to a file to save the data stored in it. When I read the file and try to convert it back it converts to a list. I added print(type()) to see what type it is going into the file and what time it is coming out.

```
    import ast
    f = open("testfile.txt", "a+")
    print (type(dic1))
    f.write(str(dic1.items()) + "\n")
    f.close()
```

this me writing it to the file

```
    ([('people', '1'), ('date', '01/01/1970'), ('t0', 'epoch'), ('time', '0'), ('p0', 'Tim Berners-Lee'), ('memory', 'This is the day time was created')])
```

this is what it looks like in the written file.

```
    loadDict = ast.literal_eval(x)
    print (type(loadDict))
```

this is the code when trying to convert back to a dictionary

Comment: To write a dictionary to a file it would be way easier to use `json.dump`, and `json.load`

Answer (score 0):

try using pickle, it is the preferred way to store and load python objects:

to store:

```
import pickle 
with open("testfile.txt", "w+") as f:
    pickle.dump(dic1,f)
```

to load:

```
import pickle 
with open("testfile.txt", "r+") as f:
    dic1 = pickle.load(f)
```

if you want to save multiple objects in a list you can save a list to the file then just load the list from file, add what you want to add to it then save it again

Comment: Just note that pickling is version-specific. So make sure you write and read from the same set-up.

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite when I was using pickle I had to load it as wb and rb. Also when I try to load it using pickle it still is reading it as a list and not a dictionary. I get this error _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '['.

Comment: @CarlosO'gorman you need to save it with pickle to load it with pickle you cant load any file with pickle